# Django : Access third party app database

Tags: django

I have a third party app ([tinycontent](https://github.com/dominicrodger/django-tinycontent)) and I want to be able to do a query on the database table of that app. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do that. Third party apps are using the same database as your own models. Just import the model and query it:

```
from tinycontent.models import TinyContent
objects = TinyContent.objects.all()
```